# Sample program where MOP and MFP are different

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I am studying the comparison between Meet over all path(MOP) and Maximum Fixed Point(MFP) in compiler optimizations. Its been said that MFP is a subset of MOP. But I couldn't find out an example in which MFP and MOP are different. Can anyone help me out with any sample program in which MFP and MOP gives different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such an example in "Monotone Data Flow Analysis Framework" by Kam and Ullman [refer this](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~achauhan/Teaching/B629/2006-Fall/CourseMaterial/1977-acta-kam-monotone.pdf).

A sample program is

```
if(<some codition>) {
  A = 2;
  B = 3;
}
else {
  A = 3;
  B = 2;
}
C=A+B;
```

If we consider the constant propagation analysis of the above program the variable C is a constant in every case. The value will be `5` if the `if statement` condition evaluates to true or false. But if we perform a fixed point analysis on the above program the `C` will never be considered as a constant whereas a MOP analysis will provide the information that `C` is a constant.